# compose string from \newcommand macros

Tags: macros

I create a new macro

```
\newcommand\var{test}
```

I would like to use the macro to compose a string, e.g. as in

```
\input{the\varfile.txt}
```

It now looks as if we have a new macro `\varfile`. How to separate the title of the macro from ordinary text? Is inserting a space the recommended solution as in:

```
\input{the\var file.txt}
```

I suppose nothing would be necessary if the variable name was followed by a symbol that cannot make part of a macro name e.g. a dot `.`.

Comment: The short answer is: yes. TeX ignores any space after a control sequence name, so `the\var file.txt` produces `thetestfile.txt`.

Comment: it's almost the only solution, other ways to terminate a macro when typesttng eg `\var{}file` would not work here (they would put `{}` into the file name)